# Object oriented constructor for Toplevel class (no side-effects)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, object-oriented-analysis, toplevel

I'm having trouble writing the constructor for a class that inherits from tkinter's Toplevel dialog. I'm calling it from another class that itself inherits from Frame. The problem I'm getting is a funny side-effect with the code I've come up with. I get an extra instance of the the calling Frame when the Toplevel dialog gets instantiated. I just wanted to ask if somebody could point me in the right direction on how to call super in the constructor for a custom Toplevel class. This inside a Python framework. The entire code I currently have follows:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class App(Frame):

    dialog = None

    def __init__(self,  root):
        super(App, self).__init__(root)
        self.root = root

        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.grid(row=3, column=1)
        self.t1 = Text(root, wrap="word")
        self.t1.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, sticky="nsew")
        self.b1 = Button(root, text=" Create ", command=self.show_dialog)
        self.b1.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10)

        root.rowconfigure(0, weight=3)
        root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def show_dialog(self):

        self.dialog = Toplevel(root)
        self.dialog.title("Child")

        # Place child window over the application window
        x = self.root.winfo_x() + self.root.winfo_width()//2 - \
            self.dialog.winfo_width()//2
        y = self.root.winfo_y() + self.root.winfo_height()//2 - \
            self.dialog.winfo_height()//2
        self.dialog.geometry(f"100x75+{x}+{y}")

        Dialog(self.t1, self.dialog)


class Dialog(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, t1, top):

        super().__init__(top)    # This doesn't work !!!

        self.top = top
        self.t1 = t1    # Text widget is passed at creation

        self.widget()

    def widget(self):
        self.e1 = Entry(self)
        self.e1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.b1 = Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.on_submit)
        self.b1.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=15)

        # self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def on_submit(self):
        self.t1.insert("insert", self.e1.get())

    def quit(self):
        self.top.destroy()


root = Tk()
root.title("Paremt")
root.geometry("400x250+400+200")

app = App(root)
app.mainloop()
```

I've updated this post to show the entire listing. I'm also trying to improve on it from comments below. I'm still getting the side effects. Now it seems to instantiate two top-level windows instead of just the class.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a complete [mcve]

Comment: Why do you create those widgets (`self.frame`, `self.e1` and `self.b1`) as children of `top` inside `Dialog` class?  They should be created as children of `Dialog` (i.e. `self`) instead.  The line `super(...).__init__(top)` is ok but it can be simply `super().__init__(top)`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you're making sense. Sorry I was a little tired. Absolutely agree. I just want to access the data in the Dialog class. Maybe if you use get() and set()? I'll come back to this sometime. Yes a reproducible example too.

Comment: Why do you create a toplevel (`self.dialog`) inside `show_dialog()` as `Dialog` is already a toplevel? Also you have similar issue mentioned in my past comment in `App` class.

Comment: I think acw1668 just pointed out the main problem with my post. I understand what is happening now. You instantiate a generic Toplevel dialog if you don't use a framework. If you're trying to have a class that inherits from Toplevel instead. Then you would just instantiate that class. It would in turn create the Toplevel window in the constructor. Why I'm getting two dialogs. One is the subclass and the other is the generic Toplevel. I'm learning tkinter and trying to apply my understanding of oo. I think I can make some progress now. I'll try post the updated code. Already much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help, I was having difficulties applying the knowledge I have of objects in Java to the Python/Tk paradigm. It all seems to work fine now. The updated listing follows.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class App(Frame):

    def __init__(self,  root):
        super(App, self).__init__(root)

        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.t1 = Text(root, wrap="word")
        self.t1.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, sticky="nsew")
        self.b1 = Button(root, text=" Create ", command=self.show_dialog)
        self.b1.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10)

        root.rowconfigure(0, weight=3)
        root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def show_dialog(self):

        Dialog(root, self.t1)

    def quit(self):
        self.destroy()


class Dialog(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, top, t1):

        super().__init__(top)

        self.t1 = t1    # Text widget is passed at creation
        self.title("Child")
        # Place child window over the application window
        x = root.winfo_x() + root.winfo_width()//2 - self.winfo_width()//2
        y = root.winfo_y() + root.winfo_height()//2 - self.winfo_height()//2
        self.geometry(f"100x75+{x}+{y}")

        self.widget()
        self.wait_visibility()
        self.transient(root)   # dialog window is related to main


    def widget(self):
        self.e1 = Entry(self)
        self.e1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.b1 = Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.on_submit)
        self.b1.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=15)

        root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)   

    def on_submit(self):
        self.t1.insert("insert", self.e1.get())

    def quit(self):
        self.destroy()


root = Tk()
root.title("Paremt")
root.geometry("400x250+400+200")

app = App(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Should those widgets created inside `App.create_widgets()` be children of `App` (a frame) instead of `root`?  Also `self.wait_visibility()` should be called before `self.transient(root)` inside `Dialog.__init__()`.

Comment: But they should be children of root, I'm passing them root in the constructor. Otherwise they do belong to the class? Yes transient is definitely after visibility ty

Comment: It is weird that widgets created inside `Frame` class are not children of the frame.

Comment: Yes but grid() should not be there. Updated ty

Comment: Then what is the point of inheriting `App` from `Frame`? Actually I would suggest to inherit `App` from `Tk`.

Comment: It's the main class in the framework. The only frame. It gets it's private place in memory. It's your application. It can control all the other dialog classes. It can use any other classes as well.